# PyCharm does not have write access to /usr/share/pycharm. Please run it by a privileged user to update

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

Need Help to update build version of Pycharm Community Edition 17.1.1 installed on Ubuntu 17.04. When "Check for Updates", the following message appears, and I am not sure how to proceed from here.

[image: PyCharm does not have write access to /usr/share/pycharm. Please run it by a privileged user to update]

How do I run it as privileged user?

Comment: @Hadi: when editing questions, product/brand names like Ubuntu, and version numbers like 17.x, do not need to be formatted using inline code. Broadly they are proper nouns, and so just need upper case initials. Thanks.

Comment: @halfer thanks for advising :)

Answer (score 22):

Please try this it works for me (do it by root):

```
cd /usr/lib/
chmod 777 -R pycharm-community/
```

Then open pycham and update.

Comment: For PyCharm Professional on MacOS, use `sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/`.

Comment: for me it adding the same permissions to the directory specified in the error message (where I installed PyCharm Professional): `sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/pycharm/`

Comment: A better solution would be to change the ownership of the folder. In my case; exracted directory was owned by `root`. you can use `sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) -R pycharm-2020.3.4`.

Comment: For 2023 version onwards, I had to run `sudo chmod 777 -R pycharm-community-2023.1.1/` in folder where pycharm is installed which was `/opt` in my case

Answer (score 5):

Please try this it works for me:

```
sudo updatedb && sudo locate pycharm.sh
sudo /path/to/pycharm.sh
```

Don't do anything else during that session, just apply the update.  Then close PyCharm and reopen normally, and you should find you are running the new version with no need to download or mess with folder permissions.

for more details check https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206601265-Fixed-PyCharm-automatic-update-fails-on-Linux-due-to-permissions

Comment: Another way to get the path to the pycharm.sh file is to check the *.desktop file using: `cat $(ls /usr/share/applications | grep pycharm)`. This contains the path to the pycharm.sh.

Answer (score 1):

sudo chown -R  /opt/yourdirectory

Answer (score 0):

The issue came up when I upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04. I tried sudo but did not worked. So had to uninstall and install again Pycharm. Now all good and gets new updates.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like a permissions issue. I think it will work if you run Pycharm via `sudo`.